# Cordova iOS app wipes indexedDB data after app closes

Tags: cordova, indexeddb

I am having an issue with a Cordova iOS that was working fine on cordova-ios 5.0.0 but after upgrade on Cordova-ios 6.0.0, after the app closes, all indexedDB is wiped.

How to fix this issue?

This is how I connect to the database:

```
var dbQuery = indexedDB.open("my_db",1);

dbQuery.onsuccess = function(){
    dbQuery.result;
};

dbQuery.onupgradeneeded = function(evt){

};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IndexedDB in Cordova used to be supported only on Windows and Android (as of https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/cordova/storage/storage.html), but is now supported by all platforms (with some limitations on browser and Windows, as of https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html).

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be true? I still see IndexedDB listed as a Storage option on the latest Cordova docs: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html